# php file upload unsuccessful

Tags: php, file-upload

what is the problem with this script, it jumps to `else` statement?

```
if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['complaint_file']['temp_name'], "../../stg/comp/".time().".".$exten))
        {
            $filename = time().".".$exten;
            $insertSQL = sprintf("UPDATE complaints SET complaint_status='CLOSED', complaint_solved_date=NOW(), complaint_remark=%s complaint_filename=%s WHERE complaint_number=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['complaint_remark'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['confirm_close_complaint'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($filename, "text"));
            $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $dacreint) or die(mysql_error());  
            header('Location: complaint-register.php?ComplaintClose=Successful');
            exit();
        }
        else {
            header("Location: complaint-register.php?FileUploadError=1");
            exit();
        }
```

My upload folder is having `777` permission.

Comment: Remove the `@` operator and check your error log. You will get an error message then, which will *tell* you what went wrong. No need to guess.

Comment: I did it and checked in error log... but nothing is there...

Comment: Try `var_dump($_FILES)` and `echo "../../stg/comp/".time().".".$exten;`.

Comment: @Travesty3 Ok i did it and got this error could you please explain me what to do next... please `array(1) { ["complaint_file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(12) "Facebook.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpeGDB8z" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(158440) } } ../../stg/comp/1334151830.jpg`

Comment: I did this `else {
    var_dump($_FILES);
    echo "../../stg/comp/".time().".".$exten;
    exit();
   }`

Comment: I don't see an error there. But I did just notice that in your if-statement you wrote 'temp_name' when it should be 'tmp_name'.

Comment: If the error log is empty, enable error reporting and ensure you log errors. Then you will see error messages. See http://php.net/error_reporting. So what @Travesty3 commented and you would see an error message there, trust me my friend. You just told PHP to move crap, and PHP errors when you do so with `move_uploaded_file`, it's just you decided to fly blind by using the `@` operator for a reason unknown to us. Please never again post code on this website that has the `@` operator in there. Thank you for making this easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your if-statement, you have `$_FILES['complaint_file']['temp_name']`. This should be `$_FILES['complaint_file']['tmp_name']` ('tmp_name', not 'temp_name').

Comment: Thanks a lot... some times typos make you feel so dumb... really million thanks to you :)

Comment: @Abhilash Shukla: The only dumb thing you did was asking a question here while using the `@` error suppression operator.

Comment: No problem. You should definitely get more familiar with `var_dump`. It should often be the first step in debugging your code.